# Enabling touch mode for edittext to enter numbers into it

Tags: android, touch, android-edittext

i have an edittext field, and i need to implement a way such that when i touch it, a window should appear with 1 to 9 number and when i select the number, the value of the edit text must be set with this number. how can i get this..???

or when i touch it edittext values must be set to 1(when touched for first time) this is the code i tried:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText edit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edit.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean flag = false;
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    flag = true;
                    break;

            }
            return flag;
            if(flag)
            {
                if ((e.getText()+"") == "")
                {
                    e.setText("1");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Integer.parseInt(e.getText())==9)
                            e.setText("1");
                    else
                        e.setText(Integer.parseInt(e.getText()+"")+1);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

but e inside the code is not found...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to only allow numbers to be entered via the keyboard, is to use the inputType attribute on an EditText:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/size"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="number"
        />
```